# Specifying decimal precision in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to cast to a specific decimal precision in BigQuery, or how is this usually done?

```
with tbl as (
  select 1.0 as fx_rate
) select cast(fx_rate as decimal(10,5)) from tbl
```

> Parameterized types are not allowed in CAST expressions.

And it seems to only allow it as an inferred decimal, which I believe here is just `DECIMAL(1)`:

```
with tbl as (
  select 1.0 as fx_rate
) select cast(fx_rate as decimal) from tbl
```

[image]

For example, in Postgres (and derivatives) I can do:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim a decimal to 2 places Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315674/trim-a-decimal-to-2-places-bigquery)

Comment: @nbk no, did you read the question? Round does the exact opposite.

Comment: you have read the error mesage, use bignumeric and reduce the number you are given, or use the string function mentioned to fill up the last digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @nbk, you may use the below to generate decimals (including leading zeros based your sample data) and then use a **string function** to specify desired precision. However, using `FORMAT()` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string) can only accomodate up to **6 decimal places only**. Also, your results will be in **STRING**.

```sql
with tbl as (
  select 1.0 as fx_rate
)
select substr(FORMAT('%F', fx_rate),1,4) from tbl
```

**Output:**

[image]

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: Using **SUBSTR()** doesn't look good.  use **FORMAT('%.3F', fx_rate)**  instead.  and you can use **CAST(1.0 AS STRING FORMAT '0.000')** as well.